# Should not a local BST node created in a function be no, as function generally loose any data created in it?

Tags: c, function, struct

I have been using functions to create Binary Search Trees, but I am stuck with this question:

Functions do not allow any local variable to be accessed outside itself. But in case of a function creating a struct node and returning its address is saved for further and being accessed by main.

Isn't it a local variable like others. I can't find what I am missing.
Please help.

Edit:

Being language specific, I mainly use C and its do return an address in case of Struct.

Comment: What language are you asking about? Most functional languages don't have the concept of returning something's address (and certainly not of an address referring to memory that is no longer accessible).

Comment: C is not a functional programming language. Please read the description of tags before you add them to your question in the future. And always tag the question with the question you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to say "with the *language* you're asking about", of course.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a pointer, something like this:

```
node_t* node_create() {
    node_t* node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));
    /* maybe populate the actual data in the node */
    return node;
}

void node_destroy(node_t* node) {
    free(node);
}
```

By using calloc or malloc, you can do "dynamic" memory allocation, and this is what lets you return structs such that you can link them into a tree or whatever and not have them go out of scope.

Comment: He doesn't *need* to return a pointer. It's perfectly acceptable to create a local variable `node_t node` and then return it by value (just like it would be with any other type of variable other than arrays, which can't be passed by value). The important thing is that if he *does* want to return a pointer, it needs to be a pointer to non-local memory, not to a local variable - thus the need for `calloc` or `malloc`.

Comment: @sepp2k: you could return a struct by value, but you couldn't then put that into a tree or similar structure.  The OP specifically mentioned putting data in trees.

Comment: I don't see why not. What's wrong with [this](https://ideone.com/INUxHz) for example? Yes, a tree needs pointers, but that doesn't mean that its nodes need to be returned as pointer from the create function or that nodes can never be passed by value. And it definitely does not mean that nodes have to live on the heap.

Comment: @sepp2k: sure, that works if you don't want the tree itself to live outside a single scope.  But as I'm sure you know, that is not typical for trees.  I'm just trying not to confuse the OP with use cases he/she probably does not have.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you return the pointer, the data is still in the memory if you didn't clean it up. You request memory to make the node, then you return the adress to that memory, if you do not clean up the memory yourself the data will still be there.
A node is a complex data type in C, meaning that you requested the memory and are responsible for the cleaning up. Unlike basic data types such as integers and chars.